# How to enable USB in VirtualBox

Tags: usb, windows, hosts

I am using Windows 8.1 as host and in VirtualBox running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, how can I make it to see the USB sticks in VirtualBox? I found lots of tutorials but all are for Ubuntu as host and Windows in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Download](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/virtualbox/4.3.18/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.18-96516.vbox-extpack) and install the extension pack. Go to settings and enable the USB controller.